# Why wont this php code work and how do i rectify it?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

hello i am getting familiar with PHP and i am wondering why this code doesn't work and is there an alternative way to make it work i.e: which other way can this be accomplished.

```
<?php
`$`fruit = array('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana', 'c' => 'cranberry');

reset(`$`fruit);
foreach(`$`fruit as `$`key => `$`val){
if((`$`key=="a" && `$`val=="apple" ) && (`$`key=="b" && `$`val=="banana") ){
echo "apple and banana";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: What the hell is all this \`$\` ???

Comment: You fix it by writing valid PHP syntax, and not wrapping every single `$` in backticks (`\``)

Comment: Yes not sure why you're using back quotes all over the place

Comment: Well you use `&&` in your if statement. Now how can the key be 2 values at the same time?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "doesn't work"? What are you trying to accomplish? If you know what you're aiming for then it's a lot easier to get there!

Comment: P.S. resetting an array before a foreach is meaningless, foreach resets the array to the beginning anyway

Comment: I do not think it's possible to ever get `apple and banana` while iterating through an array because each fruit is in a separate location.

Comment: The best answer is to read the documentations, read some tutorials, learn the basics of php.

Comment: please the back ticks were mistakes i made when putting the code here but thanks for your suggestions

Comment: @simpleigh well i actually just started studying arrays into detail and based on my previous knowledge with if statements i was wondering why in my attempt to loop through the values of an array i could not check if the condition as stated above doesn't work. I just had an explanation from Jeff Puckett II in his comment down below . Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
$fruit = array('a' => "apple", 'b' => "banana", 'c' => "cranberry");

reset($fruit);
foreach($fruit as $key => $val)
{
    if(($key=='a' && $val=="apple" ) || ($key=='b' && $val=="banana") )
    {
        echo "apple and banana";
    }
}
?>
```

As the others have mentioned, when you write PHP you are not supposed to surround the sigit ($) with quotes.

Other then fixing that issue, I noticed another issue. When you are looping through the array, the `$key` variable can only deal with one element at a time. In order for your programs if condition to be true, you required $key variable to have two values at the same time:

```
if(($key=="a" && $val=="apple" ) && ($key=="b" && $val=="banana"))
```

Notice the `&&`. You are saying that `$key` has to be equal to "a" and to "b" at the same time. $val also has to be equal to "apple" and "banana" at the same time. This condition is impossible.

Think of it this way. A variable is your hand. Your hand can only hold one thing at a time. `$key` is your left hand, and `$val` is your right. If I tell you that you can only enter my room if you are holding two things in your left hand and two things in your right hand, you will say to me, that is impossible! I can only hold one thing in my left hand, and only one thing in my right hand. This is a silly analogy but maybe it will help.

Anyway, that is why I changed the `&&` to an `||`. In my code you may notice how I changed the array identifier (`a`, `b`, `c`) from being surrounded in single quotes to double quotes. This is just my style. I like to do that.

Anyway, I hope this helps. Sorry if there are any spelling mistakes, I am in a rush and have to go.

Comment: good answer, but your output statement should be `echo "apple OR banana";`

Comment: @JeffPuckettII Haha, thanks. I did not even notice that.

Answer (score 0):

The back tics are not needed.

```
<?php
  $fruit = array('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana', 'c' => 'cranberry');
  reset($fruit); // Why?
  foreach($fruit as $key => $val){  
    // this will never be true. Guessing you want a or 
    if(($key=="a" and $val=="apple" ) and ($key=="b" and $val=="banana") ){  
      echo "apple and banana";
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: `if(($key=="a" ... ) and ($key=="b" ...` will never evaluate to true.